# WPF Canvas in ScrollViewer size to fit

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, scrollviewer

I have a Canvas inside a ScrollViewer. What I'm trying to do is size the canvas such that it will EITHER fill the ScrollViewer OR contain its child elements - whichever is larger. The challenge I have is that the MeasureOverride in the Canvas is always called with infinity - which I guess makes sense (it's in a scroller, so it can be any size it likes.) So whilst I know how much space is required by the canvas children, I don't know how big my parent is - so I can't return a minimum size (to fill the scroller viewport)

Any insight would be most welcome.

Thanks

Comment: You may be able to bind the `MinHeight` to the `Height` of the `ScrollViewer`. Something like `<Canvas MinHeight="{Binding ElementName=YourScrollViewer, Path=Height}"/>`

Answer (score 0):

What I've done is bind the `Height` and `MinHeight` of a `Canvas` to the `ActualHeight`s of the `ScrollViewer` and the `Canvas'` Content.

As the `Height` of the `Canvas` should only be the `Height` of the `ScrollViewer` when the height of the contents is less, it makes sense to set this to the `MinHeight`of the `Canvas`.

```
<ScrollViewer Name="YourScrollViewer">
    <Canvas Height="{Binding ElementName=YourContent, Path=ActualHeight}" MinHeight="{Binding ElementName=YourScrollViewer, Path=ActualHeight}">
        <StackPanel Name="YourContent"/>
    </Canvas>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Not sure it quite works in my situation. My canvas content is a bunch of Visual object (created in code) so I need to programmatically calculate their bounds etc. The canvas I have could also be scaled - and in reality I want to ensure it's actually a multiple of the scroll viewport (so there is always a margin to scroll to)

Comment: You could use a converter for the binding on `MinHeight` to get a multiple. For the `Height` I would suggest looping through your collection and using `Canvas.GetTop(Element) + Element.ActualHeight` to get the maximum value, creating a property to store this and then binding this to the `Height`

Comment: I've come up with a bit of a hack solution. I override MeasureOverride in the ScrollViewer and cache the constrain size, I then call .Measure on the Canvas. In the MeasureOverride of the Canvas I then return the parent ScrollViewer cached constrain size (adjusted for my content size and any scaling etc.) Seems to work !?

Comment: This seems awfully complex for just adjusting the height of a canvas. I would consider using a binding for `MinHeight` like in my answer (using a converter if you need a multiple). For the `Height` I would have thought looping through your collection of content to find the height needed and setting that would be easier

Comment: Changed my approach - I just implement the ScrollChangedEventHandler then adjust my canvas based on the various viewport settings. I do it in code but I guess it's akin to your binding suggestion :-)